# Why does TypeORM one-to-many/many-to-one relations not work after webpack build?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have these entities for my Postgres DB:

```
@Entity({ name: "user" })
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  // other columns

  @OneToMany(() => OTP, (otp) => otp.user)
  otps: Relation<OTP>[];
}

@Entity({ name: "OTP" })
export class OTP {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.otps)
  @JoinColumn({ name: "userId" })
  user: Relation<User>;

  // other columns
}
```

I put these in the same file to avoid any cyclic dependencies, even though I have `"target": "es2016"`,`"module": "commonjs"`, and `"esModuleInterop": true` in my tsconfig.

My queries work while i run the server with ts-node, but after building, I get these kinds of errors. Am I missing  some syntax?

```
error: TypeORMError: Cyclic dependency: ""
      at visit (/Users/jb/Work/groove-bahamas-srv/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:147:23)
      at visit (/Users/jb/Work/groove-bahamas-srv/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:164:21)
      at SubjectTopoligicalSorter.toposort (/Users/jb/Work/groove-bahamas-srv/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:143:17)
      at SubjectTopoligicalSorter.sort (/Users/jb/Work/groove-bahamas-srv/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectTopoligicalSorter.js:53:45)
      at SubjectExecutor.execute (/Users/jb/Work/groove-bahamas-srv/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/SubjectExecutor.js:91:108)
      at EntityPersistExecutor.execute (/Users/jb/Work/groove-bahamas-srv/node_modules/typeorm/persistence/EntityPersistExecutor.js:140:36)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5),
  username: 'username',
  email: 'email@email.com'
}
```

I've tried the Relation keyword from typeORM and moving entities into separate files. I'm pretty stumped. Following the example in the [docs](https://typeorm.io/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations), also fails for me on build.